# How do I get os.path.split to work with user defined askopenfilename? Would argparse or pathlib work better?

Tags: python, tkinter, user-input, user-defined-functions, argparse

I need some help on how to properly use `os.path.split` with tkinters `scrolledtext`.

I tried using `split` with the (head/tail) parts in different ways, but I have no idea how to make it work. Mainly on how to output it into a string text that can change and update on the user input. That would be next on the list, but right now I need to get this `split` part to work.

```
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, Button, Label, Grid, Entry,
scrolledtext
from os import path
import os

# FUNCTIONS

def browseFunc():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.split(usermod, filename))
    pathlabel.config(text='current path %s' % dirname)

# START

root = Tk()

# BROWSE BUTTON

browseButton = Button (root, text="Browse", command=browseFunc)
browseButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

# BROWSE BUTTON OUTPUT

pathlabel = Label(root)
pathlabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

# END
root.mainloop()
```

***If tkinter is not the right thing to use for what I want, let me know.***

## Input

**User**: select file → `H:\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\SourceFilmmaker\game\usermod\models\nitpick\test\test.dmx`

## Output

**scrolled text**:

$modelname "`nitpick\test\test`.mdl" **← takes input of askfilename and auto completes scrolled text, adds .mdl at the end**

$body "body" "`test.dmx`" **← only selected file**

$cdmaterials "`nitpick\test`" **← assuming the textures are in the materials folder and not models**

$sequence "idle" "`test.dmx`" loop fps 30 **← only selected file**

---

## Edits

I found something called `argparse` which sounds promising. I don't know if this will help me with what I'm trying to do.

Also is there a way to print a string on a specific line of `scrollingtext`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your problem arises from faulty use of os.path.dirname and os.path.split . They are complementary in the sense that basically

```
os.path.dirname(path) = os.path.split(path)[0]
```

Further you seem to pass two arguments to os.path.split, while according to the python reference it takes only one argument.

Comment: Code in my answer is meant as equality of function. Meaning that left side does same thing as right sode and yoi should uae only one of them

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.split` takes only one argument:

```
>>> os.path.split('foo/bar')
('foo', 'bar')
```

All it does is split apart the "containing directory" portion from the "file name" portion, so here the containing directory is `foo` and the file name is `bar`.  There is no notion of a file-name-extension—file names can have any number of dots in them, and, e.g., `bar.tex.txt.tar.gz` is just the *name* `bar.tex.txt.tar.gz`:

```
>>> os.path.split('bar.tex.txt.tar.gz')
('', 'bar.tex.txt.tar.gz')
```

There's no containing directory part here, so that's empty.

The result of Tkinter's `filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()` appears to always be a full path name of an existing file (this is based on a quick experiment, not any documentation; [the documentation appears to be a bit thin](https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/)), so that after `os.path.split` you should always have a non-empty directory portion and file-name portion.  However, if all you want is to replace the final `.abc` extension with `.def`, consider doing just that, without calling `os.path.split` at all:

```
>>> filename = 'some arbitrary/name.with.dots/ending with foo.abc'
>>> os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.def'
'some arbitrary/name.with.dots/ending with foo.def'
```

If you wish to limit the extensions matched, you can do that with an argument to `filedialog.askopenfilename()`.  The documentation implies that `filedialog.askopenfilename()` returns an empty string if the user presses "cancel".  However, this appears to be true *only after at least one successful selection*: instead, it returns an empty *tuple* for the very first "cancel".  So it seems best to test for this with `if not filename`:

```
def browseFunc():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='select a file',
                                          filetypes=(('py', '*.py'),
                                                     ('all', '*')))
    if not filename:
        pathlabel.config(text='no path, you chose Cancel')
    else:
        pathlabel.config(text='current path {!r}'.format(filename))
```

Incidentally, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a bit heavyweight for what it seems you're doing, but it's a handy way to express all of the kinds of manipulations you might ever want to do with paths.

Comment: I'm skimming through the pathlib docs, it's seems like the kind of thing I am looking for, but it's tricky to find the exact one. What would you recommend?

Comment: I haven't actually *used* pathlib for anything so I'm not sure.